# Java reflection with clone

Tags: java, reflection, clone

Example I have data layer after

```
public class DemoData implements Cloneable {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

I want to assign data values (DemoData) to a duplicate data (DemoData clone) layer as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoData demoData = new DemoData();
        demoData.setName("Class Sources");
        testReflectionDemo(demoData);
    }

    private static DemoData testReflectionDemo(DemoData demoData) {
        try {
            DemoData clone = (DemoData) demoData.clone();
            clone.setName(demoData.getName());
            clone.setValue(demoData.getValue());
            return clone;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I want to convert the method testReflectionDemo(DemoData demoData) to  method testReflectionDemo(T t) reflection as shown below.I do not know how to continue, please help me

```
public <T> T testReflectionDemo(T t){
        Class<?> aClass = t.getClass();
        for (Method method : aClass.getMethods()) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of `clone.setName(demoData.getName()); clone.setValue(demoData.getValue());`? Do you understand how cloning works?

Comment: Because the statement runs correctly, I think it can work, in the actual program I have included the following function

clone.setName (getContent (demoData.getName ()));

Comment: So what if it runs? That doesn't make it correct or necessary.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. There isn't a generally correct way to copy every possible kind of object. How an object should be copied, and even what it means to copy an object in the first place, is something that only the implementation of and specification for that particular object should be concerned with.

Comment: Hi thanks  for your suggestions Because the input type handles the same type as the result returned "<T> T testReflectionDemo(T t)", I think I can apply Reflection to it

I have not thought of a better way,I think it is necessary for me

Comment: I'm very confused as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you two for helping me realize the mistake,I will learn refection and clone again.

Comment: It could be helpful if you described what you actually want to achieve. As others said, a generic "copy"-method that works for *arbitrary* objects is difficult (or even impossible). But in many cases, the goal is much simpler. If you just want to copy a plain Java Bean (with getters/setters that only use primitive types, arrays and strings), there certainly are solutions out there.

Comment: Reflection is rarely a good solution to anything.  It circumvents compiler checks for type safety and method signatures, it is hard to debug, and it is rarely if ever optimized by the JIT at runtime.  Even if you have a hundred data classes, you’re better off writing an explicit clone method for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the argument of `testReflectionDemo` is a javabean,it means that the class of argument have several a pair method of `setXXX` and 'getXXX`,and the`getXXX`don't have argument,the`setXXX` just have one argument.If is this,the following code can copy the property from old object to new object.

```
    Class<?> aClass = t.getClass();
    Object result = aClass.newInstance();
    Map<String,MethodHolder> map=new HashMap<>();
    for (Method method : aClass.getMethods()) {
        if(method.getName().startsWith("get") && method.getParameterTypes().length==0){
            String property=method.getName().substring(3);
            MethodHolder hodler = map.get(property);
            if(hodler ==null){
                map.put(property, new MethodHolder(property, method, null));
                continue;
            }
            hodler.getMethod=method;
        }else if (method.getName().startsWith("set") && method.getParameterTypes().length==1) {
            String property=method.getName().substring(3);
            MethodHolder holder = map.get(property);
            if(holder ==null){
                map.put(property, new MethodHolder(property, null, method));
                continue;
            }
            holder.setMethod=method;
        }
    }
    List<MethodHolder> collect = map.values().stream().filter(item -> item.setMethod != null && item.getMethod != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (MethodHolder holder : collect) {
        Object property = holder.getMethod.invoke(t);
        holder.setMethod.invoke(result,property);
    }
    return (T)result;
```

The `MethodHolder` just have some field:

```
public static class MethodHolder{
    private String property;
    private Method getMethod;
    private Method setMethod;

    public MethodHolder() {
    }

    public MethodHolder(String property, Method getMethod, Method setMethod) {
        this.property = property;
        this.getMethod = getMethod;
        this.setMethod = setMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MethodHolder)) return false;
        MethodHolder that = (MethodHolder) o;
        return Objects.equals(property, that.property);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(property);
    }
}
```

Pay attention of that the following code just make shallow copy.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for the help for my question,I've removed the clone method, I just applied reflection.Hi @dabaicai.Your code helped me with the idea,I thought passing the value to the private field would be easier a little.

```
public static <T> T clazzClone(T t) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Class<?> clazzRoot = t.getClass();

        Object newInstance = clazzRoot.newInstance();
        Field[] fieldsClone = newInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field fieldClone : fieldsClone) {
            fieldClone.setAccessible(true);
            fieldClone.set(newInstance, getContent(t, fieldClone.getName()));
        }
        return (T) newInstance;
    }

    private static String getContent(Object aClass, String name) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field declaredField = aClass.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        return (String) declaredField.get(aClass);
    }
```

My program means when I need to edit user input data to output the results I want,with a common filter function

```
 fieldClone.set(newInstance,methodYourEdit(getContent(t, fieldClone.getName())));
```